# How I can to change path for blockchain data for Parity wallet on linux mint 18.2?

Tags: parity, linux

I'm the newbie on Linux and blockhain.  I'm have installed Linux on the small piece of my hard drive (50 GB), so I want to know how to change the directory for blockchain data on my external hard drive.  I use Linux Mint 18.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how Parity is started. If you're starting from the command line, you can use these flags:

```
-d --base-path PATH     Specify the base data storage path.
--db-path PATH          Specify the database directory path
                        (default: $BASE/chains).
--keys-path PATH        Specify the path for JSON key files to be found
                        (default: $BASE/keys).
```

If Parity is not started from the command line, you should first figure out how to make it not start automatically (that depends on your operating system -- on Mac your remove the LaunchAgent).

There also a user_defualts file that you can search for information about. That lets you set certain startup params. I'm not sure if the path variables are in that file or not.

Before you do anything though, please make sure to backup your private keys. Do not say I didn't warn you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't mention that I don't finish synchronization because space at "home" directory has only 15 GB. So I do not have private keys yet.

Comment: Also, when I type "-d --base-path/media/pgs/My Passport/Ethereum"
 in a terminal, it turns "-d: command not found". Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: `parity -d ...`

Comment: When I type "parity -d --base-path/media/pgs/My Passport/Ethereum" it turns out "Invalid arguments."

Comment: You can get help on parity with `parity --help`.  I simply copied and pasted the help text, but it looks like you can use either `parity -d <your_path>` or `parity --base-path <your_path>`, but not both. Sorry I wasn't more clear.

Comment: Oh Dear... That appears when I try to type this:                                         parity -d/media/pgs/My Passport/Ethereum
Invalid arguments.

Comment: parity --base-path/media/pgs/My Passport/Ethereum
Unknown flag: '--base-path/media/pgs/My'

Comment: Maybe it because I do not finish synchronization?

Comment: Put a space after --base-path or -d. Plus, I think, if you're changing the location of the chain, it will start a new re-sync anyway.

Comment: No, still don't work:  parity  --base-path /media/pgs/My Passport/Ethereum
Invalid arguments.

Comment: Quote the path. `parity --base-path "/media/pgs/My Passport/Ethereum" ` (I this doesn't work, I don't know what the problem is.)

Comment: "Plus, I think, if you're changing the location of the chain, it will start a new re-sync anyway" - it's okay, I just try run and complete synchronization in new path with enough capacity of hard drive.

Comment: We did it!  With quotes, it works! Thank You very much for spending Your time on me!